# PHP SoapClient is interpreting XML array as an object and not array

Tags: php, soap

I cannot get the right soap response from the SoapClient. Here is a pure soap response I have in the Soap Service:

```
  <a:Result>
    <b:WindowTypes>
                    <b:Window>
                        <b:WindowID>xxx</b:WindowID>
                    </b:Window>
                    <b:Window>
                        <b:WindowID>yyy</b:WindowID>
                    </b:Window>
                    <b:Window>
                        <b:WindowID>zzz</b:WindowID>
                    </b:Window>
     </b:WindowTypes>
  </b:Result>
```

PHP interprets it like:

```
["Result"]=>
object(stdClass)#597 (6) {
   ["WindowTypes"]=>
  object(stdClass)#518 (1) {
    ["Window"]=>
    array(32) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#519 (1) {
        ["WindowID"]=>
        string(3) "xxx"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#520 (1) {
        ["WindowID"]=>
        string(3) "yyy"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#521 (1) {
        ["WindowID"]=>
        string(3) "zzz"
      }
 }}
```

I want to have this structure:
WindowTypes(**array**)->Window(**object**)->WindowID(**object**)

But i get this:
WindowTypes(**object**)->Window(**array**)->WindowID(**object**)

I guess this is because WindowTypes are not explicitly not annotated as an array (by the way in C# this works fine and windowtypes is an array), but obviously it should be an array, because it contains multiple Window elements...

There is also no way to change or update SOAP structure, unfortunately.
I use PHP5 + SoapClient